# Apache POI error message displayed for RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL

Tags: java, apache, xssf

I have code for witting data in Excel file whenever cell founds empty. However when i type below code it gives error. :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import Config.Constants;

public class ExcelUtils {

 private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
 private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
 private static XSSFCell Cell;
 private static XSSFRow Row, xRow;

 public static void setExcelFile(String Path, String SheetName) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
  ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
  // ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
 }



 public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName) throws Exception {
  ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
  try {


   Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
   String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
   return CellData;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return "";
  }
 }
 public static int getRowCount(String SheetName) {
  ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
  int number = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
  return number;
 }

 //This method is to get the Row number of the test case
 //This methods takes three arguments(Test Case name , Column Number & Sheet name)
 public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum, String SheetName) throws Exception {
  int i;
  ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
  int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);
  for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
   if (ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, colNum, SheetName).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)) {
    break;
   }
  }
  return i;
 }

 //This method is to get the count of the test steps of test case
 //This method takes three arguments (Sheet name, Test Case Id & Test case row number)
 public static int getTestStepsCount(String SheetName, String sTestCaseID, int iTestCaseStart) throws Exception {
  for (int i = iTestCaseStart; i <= ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName); i++) {
   if (!sTestCaseID.equals(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, SheetName))) {
    int number = i;
    return number;
   }
  }
  ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
  int number = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
  return number;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
 public static void setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName) throws Exception {
  try {

   ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
   Row = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
   xRow = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);
   // Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL;

   //  ExcelWBook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
   //Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, Blank);
   Cell = xRow.getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

   if (Cell == null) {
    Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);
    Cell.setCellValue(Result);
   } else {
    Cell.setCellValue(Result);
   }
   // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constants.Path_TestData);
   //ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
   ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
   //fileOut.flush();
   fileOut.close();
   ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(Constants.Path_TestData));
  } catch (Exception e) {
   DriverScript.bResult = false;
  }
 }
}
```

Error message:

> MissingCellPolicy cannot be resolved or is not a field

Whereas when i use "`Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL`" it says method is deprecated. Can i have some solution for this both problems to run my code succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

Cell has many types and you should get value according to its type, getStringCellValue() is not enough

I often use this code to get

```
switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
    case FORMULA:
        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        switch (cellValue.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case BOOLEAN:
                value = Boolean.toString(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                value = Double.toString(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                break;
            case STRING:
                value = cellValue.getStringValue();
                break;
        }
        break;
    case BOOLEAN:
        value = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case NUMERIC:
        value = Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    default:
        value = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
}
```